Geodesics in non-convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a non-convex connected subset. Let $x,y \in \text{int}(U)$ be such that the straight line joining them does not lie entirely in $U$. Let $\gamma$ be the shortest path in $U$ joining $x$ and $y$. Does $\gamma$ necessarily have to intersect the boundary?
I think the answer has to be positive after looking at a few figures of non-convex subsets, but I couldn't find an argument for it. The vague argument I had in my mind is as follows:
As the straight line goes outside $U$ and it is a limit of paths of decreasing length, the shortest path in $U$ should be as close as possible to the straight line, thus it should touch the boundary!
I was thinking generally about geodesics with respect to induced metrics on non-convex subsets of a Riemannian 2-manifold.

If $\gamma$ lies entirely in the interior of $U$, you should be able to find a neighborhood around a point of on $\gamma$ contained in $U$ in which replacing $\gamma$ by a straight line segment gives a shorter path; you should play with the path integral a bit and see whether this works out. Also n.b. that $\gamma$ doesn't need to exists in the first place (consider a punctured disk).

You also cannot say "the shortest path" since such a shortest path might not be non-unique even if it exists.
